# Unsupported API warnings in Google Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following warnings in the pre-launch report from Google Play.

I am at a loss as to how to correct these. Any help or recommendations is appreciated I am having lots of issues here:

```html
Android compatibility
 We’ve detected that your app is using unsupported APIs. Tests may not have found all unsupported APIs. Learn more
 
 Unsupported
  12 warnings identified
 The following APIs are greylisted and Google can’t guarantee that they will work on existing versions of Android. Some may be already be restricted for your target SDK
 
 
 API Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V
 11 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.
  
 API Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputFrameCount()I
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputSamplingRate()I
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V
 1 occurrence identified
  
 API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V
 1 occurrence identified
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and also have no idea how to find where these unsupported calls are being made in my code. I have searched my `app/src/main/java/*` directory for various text snippets from the error and can find nothing in my source at all. How can these be tracked down in order to correct them?

Comment: I have same issue but all such API calls are inside of libraries added as dependencies for my apk. Weird thing there that all of them are from Google - Google Play Games and Firebase :\

Comment: I have the same issues, and my app is 99% C++ so all the warnings comes from the Google API's I support via gradle I suppose.

Comment: Has anyone figured out where these are coming form with the Google decencies. I have the same thing and am OT using any 3rd party API calls.

Comment: Same problems. When I run veridex, all of my apps have > 50 violations. Even for a new generated app with ArticFox 2021.1.1, more than 40 violations are printed. It seems to me, that this tools from Google are not very helpful but infact rahter the opposite. On the other side, with the StrictMode test detectNonSdkApiUsage, no violations is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These warnings refer to the usage of restricted non-SDK interfaces.
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

These calls may lead to incorrect behavior or app crashes. It is recommended to avoid them. All usages belong to blacklist, greylist, or whitelist. If you can't get rid of these usages, check affiliation to list. Only blacklisted calls lead to crashes. Also, just to remind, Android Q (targetSDK=29) has updated blacklist
https://developer.android.com/preview/non-sdk-q

Comment: I found this exact info on the Google Developers' pages, but it does not really help either the OP or myself and others like us who are struggling to find where these calls are being made. We understand that the calls should not be being made, but if we can't find the calls in our code we can't even begin to work out how to correct them.

Comment: For info, I am using Android Studio and I get no warnings via the Long, during build or during debugging. I only see these errors in the Developers' console pre-launch report.

Comment: I have 23 such issues in 2 of my apps and all of those issues are originated from androidx libraries from google, like ViewUtils and whatnot. Talk about irony

Comment: I have a few of these warnings. One is `Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;->setTouchModal`, which seems like a [Google one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setTouchModal(boolean))

Comment: I have similar warnings on my Alpha release pre-launch report. I'm wondering if warnings like these, once promoted to production, will cause your app to be rejected?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I also checked that pagehttps://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces but you know what that is not helping Man how can I find the exact error in code and remove them, where to find this unsupported api's

Answer (score 18):

I had similar issues I got the NonSdkApiUsedViolation Logs by adding the below code in onCreate() of my MainActivity, it gave me the precise location of the API call causing it.

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.contentEquals("debug")) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy
        .Builder()
        .detectAll()             // Checks for all violations
        .penaltyLog()            // Output violations via logging
        .build()
    );

    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy
        .Builder()
        .detectNonSdkApiUsage()  // Detect private API usage
        .penaltyLog()            // Output violations via logging
        .build()
    );
}
```

When running your application, should the execution of any code trigger a `StrictMode` violation, you should see a stack trace in the logging output indicating what triggered it:

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=28 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1596)
  ...
```

After manually testing your application, searching your log output for `StrictMode` should help you find these easily.

[Google's documentation on StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) also provides some additional guidance:

> If you find violations that you feel are problematic, there are a variety of tools to help solve them: threads, Handler, AsyncTask, IntentService, etc. But don't feel compelled to fix everything that StrictMode finds. In particular, many cases of disk access are often necessary during the normal activity lifecycle. Use StrictMode to find things you did by accident. Network requests on the UI thread are almost always a problem, though.

Comment: I do not understand, an APK in the results pre-launch 0 errors, republished after 12 hours (the same apk to which I changed only one image) now returns with 9 non-SDK interface errors ...mah.
Moreover the log report on the play console does not give any way to detect what and who should be replaced and with what ...Do they still have a tool that clearly indicates what I should change?

Comment: Upvoted because this helps you find where the problem's in your code, even when it's called through a 3rd party library.

Comment: Excuse my naivety, but how exactly does this help?  If I add the above to my code, is there a log somewhere I can check or is there something else?

Comment: You inspect the logs with logcat, using `adb logcat` or other log viewer tools. There is also `StrictMode.enableDefaults();` with recommended options. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode#enableDefaults()

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xamarin, I believe the equivalent of Kailash's answer is:

```
#if DEBUG
    StrictMode.SetThreadPolicy(
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .DetectAll()
            .PenaltyLog()
            .Build());

    StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(
       new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .DetectNonSdkApiUsage()
            .PenaltyLog()
            .Build());
#endif // DEBUG
```

Comment: There is also `StrictMode.EnableDefaults();` with recommended options. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode#enableDefaults()